# Конструирование linq-запросов с .ThenInclude() на лету

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Надоело писать однотипные запросы, решил написать один раз конструктор запросов:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyEntity>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<MyEntity, object>>[] includes)
{
    var query = this.ApplicationDbContext.MyEntitys.AsQueryable();
    if (includes.Any())
    {
        foreach (var include in includes)
            query = query.Include(include);
    }

    return await query.Where(predicate)
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.Created)
                 .AsNoTracking()
                 .ToListAsync();
}
```

И всё было хорошо:

```
await this.MyEntityRepository.GetAsync(Model.GbFilter, x => x.Manager, x => x.Orders))
```

...пока не начались запросы не просто с `.Include()` - но и с `.ThenInclude()`

Как можно переделать данный конструктор, чтобы можно было использовать `.ThenInclude()`?

Comment: Покажите, как бы вы хотели пользоваться этим методом

Comment: Кстати, проверка `if (includes.Any())` в вашем методе не нужна, если массив пустой, то цикл выполнится ноль раз

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да вот не особо приходит в голову как это вызвать, чтобы и автокомплит на точке срабатывал (особенно на Orders, там ICollection) и понятно было. Может и не стоило вообще в эту тему лезть?

Comment: Я немного поэкспериментировал и пришел к выводу, что в текущем виде невозможно будет статически определить значение параметра типа `TProperty` для `ThenInclude`. Можно, наверное, сделать это как-то динамически, но код будет уродлив

Comment: Здесь кусочек того, что я пробовал начать писать: https://pastebin.com/3iHULGHa

Comment: Подождем, может кто-то что-то еще предложит...

Comment: @АндрейNOP а чего ждать то, я вот, например, не имею доступа к pastebin - потому не могу даже ваше предложение поглядеть. А если у кого будет другой ответ - пусть пишет его вторым ответом, рядом с вашим.